# Output returns from long running python script called by php not displayed on web-page

Tags: php, python, ajax

I am simply calling python script from my php program and I need to display the output return from python script to webpage. I am new to this, so I tried many ways to get the output return,

1.

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('python script.py "ab" "cd" ');
$output = shell_exec($command);
```

2.

```
$output = shell_exec('python script.py "ab" "cd" ');
print $output;
```

3.

```
$command = system('python script.py "ab" "cd" ',$output);
echo "output is ".$output;
echo "command is".$command;
```

4.

```
$command = passthru ('python script.py "ab" "cd" ');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
```

5.

```
exec('python script.py "ab" "cd" ', $output, $return_var);
echo $output;
echo $return_var;
```

If time taken taken by python script is less, then I able to get the output return to my php program and able to display on my web page.

```
print "Hello"
print "world"
```

But when my python program is calling any background process, which taking more time and giving output after few seconds, then that parts are not returning to the php program.

```
print "Hello"
returned_value=subprocess.check_output('ssh -p 29418 xyz.com --format=JSON', shell=True)
print returned_value
```

I tried to include sleep in php program but it is not helping as output is already returned. Some posts suggested to use `Ajax` Whether that is the only and correct way to solve this question?

Thanks in advance for your help or suggestion.